# Logging in through Keycloak with Selenium devservice

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, quarkus, quarkus-oidc

I have a Quarkus webservice that used `oidc` to perform auth, and handle the login flow.

This works great in devmode. However, tests make this a bit harder.

I'm leveraging a Selenium testcontainer to provide a browser instance within a docker container. This works fine for pages that don't need a login, with the caveat that the service being tested needs to be hit using the `host.testcontainers.internal` hostname, as opposed to `localhost`. It is this fact that seems to be keeping keycloak from working;

The devservice spins up a Keycloak instance at `localhost`, and that is what is set for `quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url`, and thus the url that a user gets redirected to for login. Unfortunately, since in the testcontainers browser, `localhost` refers to the seelenium container, and can't connect to Keycloak.

I have tried setting a consistent port for keycloak, and setting the host directly, but then it seems that the running service instance doesn't have access to `host.testcontainers.internal`, meaning it can't do its required rest calls anyways. In simpler terms, when `localhost` is the host configured for keycloak, the user in the browser cannot access keycloak. When `host.testcontainers.internal` is, the service being tested can't. This leaves me a little stuck. I could see a path forward if these were integration tests run in container mode, but this is in the normal test scope...

How I am setting up the selenium testcontainer:

https://github.com/Epic-Breakfast-Productions/OpenQuarterMaster/blob/f7746ae91d3cb9a15dd3e281f07df866dcad484d/software/open-qm-base-station/src/test/java/tech/ebp/oqm/baseStation/testResources/lifecycleManagers/SeleniumGridServerManager.java

```java
@Slf4j
public class SeleniumGridServerManager implements QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager {
    
    public static final boolean RECORD = true;
    
    private BrowserWebDriverContainer<?> browserWebDriverContainer = null;
    
    private boolean uiTest = false;
    
    @Getter
    private WebDriver driver = null;
    
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> start() {
        if (!uiTest) {
            log.info("Test not calling for ui.");
            return Map.of();
        }
        if (this.browserWebDriverContainer == null || !this.browserWebDriverContainer.isRunning()) {
            log.info("Starting Selenium WebGrid server.");
            StopWatch sw = StopWatch.createStarted();
            
            this.browserWebDriverContainer = new BrowserWebDriverContainer<>()
                                                 .withCapabilities(new FirefoxOptions())
                                                 .withReuse(false)
                                                 .withAccessToHost(true)
//                                               .withNetworkAliases("host.docker.internal:localhost")
            ;
            
            if (RECORD) {
                File recordingDir = new File(
                    "build/seleniumRecordings/"
                    + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm").format(new Date())
                );
                recordingDir.mkdirs();
                this.browserWebDriverContainer = this.browserWebDriverContainer.withRecordingMode(
                    RECORD_ALL,
                    recordingDir,
                    VncRecordingContainer.VncRecordingFormat.MP4
                );
                
            }
            this.browserWebDriverContainer.start();
            
            sw.stop();
            
            log.info(
                "Started selenium testcontainer in {}: {}; {}",
                sw,
                this.browserWebDriverContainer.getDockerImageName(),
                this.browserWebDriverContainer.isCreated() && this.browserWebDriverContainer.isRunning()
            );
            log.info("Getting web driver");
            this.driver = this.browserWebDriverContainer.getWebDriver();
            log.info("Got web driver.");
        } else {
            log.info("Selenium grid server already running.");
        }
        return Map.of(
            "runningInfo.hostname",
            Utils.HOST_TESTCONTAINERS_INTERNAL,
            

            "quarkus.keycloak.devservices.enabled",
            "true",
            "quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url",
            "http://"+Utils.HOST_TESTCONTAINERS_INTERNAL+":8089/realms/oqm"
        );
    }
    
    @Override
    public void stop() {
        if (this.browserWebDriverContainer == null) {
            log.info("Web browser container never started.");
            return;
        }
        
        log.info("Stopping web driver container.");
        
        if (this.driver != null) {
            this.driver.close();
        }
        if (this.browserWebDriverContainer != null) {
            this.browserWebDriverContainer.close();
            this.browserWebDriverContainer.stop();
        }
        
        this.driver = null;
        this.browserWebDriverContainer = null;
        
        log.info("Stopped web driver server.");
    }
    
    public void triggerRecord(TestDescription description, Optional<Throwable> throwable) {
        if (this.browserWebDriverContainer != null) {
            log.info("Triggering browser container to save recording of test.");
            this.browserWebDriverContainer.afterTest(description, throwable);
        }
    }
    
    public void beforeTest(TestDescription description) {
        if (this.browserWebDriverContainer != null) {
            this.browserWebDriverContainer.beforeTest(description);
            
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void init(Map<String, String> initArgs) {
        QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager.super.init(initArgs);
        this.uiTest = Boolean.parseBoolean(initArgs.getOrDefault(TestResourceLifecycleManager.UI_TEST_ARG, Boolean.toString(this.uiTest)));
    }
    
    //  public WebDriver getDriver() {
    //      return this.browserWebDriverContainer.getWebDriver();
    //  }
}
```

Is there any way to resolve this? Also thinking if `host.testcontainers.internal` was accessible from the host, could be a solution, but unsure of the best way to acomplish this; I would rather not have to have my `hosts` modified for automated tests.